# Is it possible to attach a workflow to a task list on MOSS 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow

I have tried but for some reason the workflow is not triggered.

Comment: Can you give more information? What have you tried? Anything in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is allowed. I myself used it for Task list.

Answer (score 0):

It should works as for all other kinds of lists.